# ¿Solución optimizada para recorrer JSON y condicionar resultados?

Tags: javascript, json

quiero recorrer un JSON en el que tengo guardado un listado de errores, me gustaríar una solución lo más optimizada posible en cuanto a código ya que es demasiado extenso y mi solución tal vez no sea la mejor y conlleve muchos "if" anidados.

El ejemplo de JSON es: (lo he reducido para el ejemplo)

```
{
    "errorList":
            [
                {
                    "propertyName":"StartDate",
                    "error":"wrong",
                    "value":"2017-06-30T00:00:00.000Z"
                },
                {
                    "propertyName":"EndDate",
                    "error":"wrong",
                    "wrongValue":"2017-07-30T00:00:00.000Z",
                    "value":"2017-07-30T00:00:00.000Z"
                },
                {
                    "propertyName":"nifCif",
                    "error":"empty"
                },
                {
                    "propertyName":"ProductData",
                    "error":"empty"
                }
            ]
}
```

La solución que he intentado es:

Guardar el JSON como objeto, recorrer cada uno de sus campos y luego ir anidando ifs con distintas condiciones:

```
var objErrList = JSON.parse(errorList);
for(var j = 0; j < objErrList.length; j++) {

    if (objErrList[j].propertyName === "StartDate") {

            if (objErrList[j].error === "wrong") {
                    salida = "X";
            } else if (objErrList[j].error === "empty") {
                    salida = "campo vacío");
            }

    }

    // ... Así sucesivamente el resto de IFs
}
```

La pregunta es: **¿Hay alguna forma más óptima de recorrer un JSON y condicionar la salida mediante IF anidados?** Ya que de esta forma, ¿tendría que repetir por cada propertyName diferente las condiciones?

Necesito que:
- Si el atributo propertyName coincide con el que busco, valore el atributo error, pero si no existe que mande mensaje por pantalla.
- En caso de que exista, que valore que si "error" es "wrong" guarde una X y si es "empty" guarde "campo vacío"

Esto repetido para cada property diferente (Y hay cientos para valorar...)

Answer (score 3):

Para recorrer el JSON no lo se, pero en vez de hacer ifs anidados por qué no utilizas objetos de Javascript? Utilizalos a modo de tabla hash, incluso para un futuro puedes hasta asignar funciones a posiciones de tu tabla hash (si llegase a ser necesario).Algo como esto podría valerte:

```
var tabla_errores = {
    'wrong':"valor de salida",
    (...)
};
//Para utilizarlo
salida = tabla_errores[objErrList[j].error];
```

De esta forma el coste para obtener una salida en función al tipo de error es Cte. y no dependiente del numero de errores distintos que tengas.

Puedes mirar documentación referente a objetos javascript [aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp).